# Python regular expression replacement based on content

Tags: python, regex

```
s1='<table>abdjjc eoafl japoge</table>'
s2='<table>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>'
```

I want to use regular expression to replace all the text in the format of " some contents ", such as s1.  but I don't want to replace it if the word "Item" is in it, such as s2. I tried the code below, but it failed to identify Item.

```
s1=re.sub(r'<table.*?>.*?[^Item].*?</table>',' ',s1)
```

If there is no way to accomplish the task above, is it possible to use regular expression based on length?I want to replace the text in the format of " some contents " only if the whole match is longer than a certain length. I am asking because the text with 'Item' in it is usually short and it might be a way to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily do-able with a zero-width negative lookahead to ensure that `Item` does not appear next:

```
In [19]: s1='<table>abdjjc eoafl japoge</table>'

In [20]: s2='<table>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>'

In [21]: re.sub(r'^<table>(?!.*Item).*</table>', 'FOO', s1)
Out[21]: 'FOO'

In [22]: re.sub(r'^<table>(?!.*Item).*</table>', 'FOO', s2)
Out[22]: '<table>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>'
```

Here the mentioned negative lookahead pattern is `(?!.*Item)`, coming after `<table>` to ensure that `Item` does not occur in the string anytime later.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the negative lookahead pattern! One problem I have is that it still matches s1 below, whenever there is a '>' after the word 'Item'. It seems the non-greedy part doesn't work. I tried `re.sub(r'(<table.*?>(?!.*Item).*</table>)', 'FOO', s1)` ,  ` s1='<table a>abdjjc Item >ljapoge</table>'`

Comment: @ClaireCui I can't reproduce. Could you please give a clear example?

Comment: `s1='<table a>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>'
print re.sub(r'(<table.*?>(?!.*Item).*</table>)', 'FOO', s1)
s2='<table a>abdjjc Item <> ljapoge</table>'
print re.sub(r'(<table.*?>(?!.*Item).*</table>)', 'FOO', s2)` For the code I above, it doesn't match s1 but it matches s2. I don't want to match s2 since it also has Item in it. Thank you!

Comment: @ClaireCui Your Regex pattern does not match with what i've provided. Anyway, seeing your latest examples, check `re.sub(r'^(?!.*Item)<table.*?>.*</table>', 'FOO', s2)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
s1 = re.sub(r'<table.*?>(?:(?!Item).)*?</table>',' ',s1)
```

Possibly with the `DOTALL` mode for multiple lines.
Or use a parser altogether. `[^Item]` is a negated character class and matches the characters on their own, meaning not `I`, not `t`, not `e` and not `m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a function and extract only what you want and leave the rest as it is :

```
import re
s1='<table>abdjjc eoafl japoge</table>'
s2='<table>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>'

pattern=r'(?:<table>)(\w.+?)(?:<\/table>)'

s_all=[s1,s2]
def replacing(s):
    store=[]
    for i in s_all:
        if 'Item' in i:  #if the condition is true don't do anything to text
            store.append(i)

        else:            #if condition is false now replace that stuff with your 'some content'
            match=re.search(pattern,s1)

            replace=re.sub(match.group(1),' some contents ',s1)
            store.append(replace)

    return store

print(replacing(s_all))
```

output:

```
['<table> some contents </table>', '<table>abdjjc Item ljapoge</table>']
#now save this result to new file or whatever you want to do with it.
```